# What do circles in dock right-click menu mean?

Tags: macos

For some apps, I see this on right-click:

[image]

The checkmark: the top window.

The diamond: the minimized window/s.

The circles: what do they mean? Do they have a general meaning across different apps?

Answer (score 3):

Those are buffers which have unsaved changes. I don't use BBEdit, but that is how SublimeText and Word do it. It's probably an attribute which OSX reads and uses automatically. Another signal for this state is a white dot inside the red close dot of the window.

Comment: What does "buffers which have unsaved changes" mean?

Comment: It's a document that has not been saved to disk. It's "buffered" in memory. Sorry, I used old unix terminology.

Comment: But in the screenshot, that's a search window, not a document. What then is the user to make of the circle? What does the circle in that screenshot mean?

Comment: For some reason Script Editor doesn't use circles in dockmenu, even as the windows are unsaved and have a black dot in the red button.

Answer (score 3):

In apps such as Terminal, the circle indicates that the application has a window in which a process is running. The window in focus will always have a checkmark, so you will only see the dot when the process is running in a window which is not in focus.

Comment: "inactive windows" meaning?

Comment: By "inactive windows", I mean those windows which are not in focus.

Comment: Btw, is this of the same "general meaning" as the circle shown by BBEdit? Or is Terminal using the circle in a specialized way?

Comment: @Pacerier Good question. I am only guessing here, but I assume that the circle is essentially meant to be a warning saying, "The window with a circle needs attention before closing this application." This would make sense both for unsaved changes in an app like BBEdit and for some unfinished process running in the Terminal.

Comment: Is this something that the OS do by itself without the programmer concerning himself with it, or is this "opt in" by the app programmer?

Comment: The app programmer chooses whether or not to implement the dot. Apple recommends doing so if not using auto save. Here’s a link regarding this:  https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/system-capabilities/auto-save/

Answer (score 1):

It's a guideline of mac software design provided by apple.
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/menus/menu-anatomy/

> Checkmark   In the Window menu, the active document; in other menus, an
>   attribute that applies to the entire selection.   Dash    An attribute
>   that applies to only part of the selection.   Bullet  A window with
>   unsaved changes (typically, when Auto Save is not available).
>     Diamond In the Window menu, a document that is currently minimized in
>   the Dock.